# Can't Send Friend Gift

Tags: pokemon-go

I've historically been able to send gifts to a particular friend, but now some days I've been unable to send gifts to that friend. Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you tap the grayed-out gift button, an error message appears telling you why you cannot send a gift. The most common reasons that you would not be able to send a gift are:

1. "You already sent this Trainer a Gift today". This is also indicated by a gray arrow icon on the friends list screen.
2. "Your friend still has an unopened gift from you"
3. "You have no Gifts in your inventory. Visit a PokéStop to look for them!"